# Git Merge ignores files that were reverted from develop but added on feature branch

Tags: git, git-merge, pull-request

I have 2 branches **develop** & **feature**. I did a **commit A** on *develop* *branch*, then I reverted it.

Then I did another **commit B** on *feature* *branch*, which modifies the same file ***modified then reverted*** on *develop branch*.

Now, when I try to create a Pull Request to merge *feature branch* into *develop branch*, the files modified in **commit B** are ignored and do not appear neither as conflict, nor as edited and merged files in my pull request.

Where is the problem ?

Comment: Not enough information to diagnose. This can happen if the change you made on feature happens to match one or more changes in develop. The two sides agree, so there is no net change.

Comment: not really the case, The file was in state 1, then changed to state 2, got reverted to state 1 again (all these steps were done on develop).
On feature branch, the file changed to state 2. 
During Merge of feature into develop, the file is shown as it is in state 1.

Comment: What was the (type of) change in commit B? Try doing a diff between B and A2 (reverted) to see if there is actually anything there.

Comment: juste code modification within file, no move, no delete, no add

Comment: I cannot reproduce. `git init; echo hi>foo; git add foo; git commit -m hi; git checkout -b feature; echo change>foo; git commit -am change; git checkout master; echo change>foo; git commit -am change2; echo hi>foo; git commit -am back; git merge feature` - the result of the merge is that the file is changed to `change`.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can replay your local feature branch on top of the updated develop branch:

```
git checkout feature
git fetch
git rebase origin/develop
```

That way, you are only publishing new commits on top of the latest state of the develop branch.

```
git push --force
# that will update your existing PR, or make a new one
```